# Why can't I escape special character

Tags: python

My code is

**hexviewer.py:**

```
def hex_viewer(filename):
    data = open(filename,"rb").read()
    listofhex = map(lambda x: b"%02X" % ord(x),data)
    listofchar = map(lambda x: "%s" % x,data)
    print "\n".join(["{0}\t{1}".format(" ".join(listofhex[x:x+10])," ".join(listofchar[x:x+10])  ) for x in xrange(0,len(listofhex),10)]  )
hex_viewer("hexviewer.txt")
```

and my source file

**hexviewer.txt:**

```
hello 
world
```

output in I think should be

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 0D 0A 77 6F   h e l l o   \r \n w o
72 6C 64                        r l d
```

but output is

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 0D 0A 77 6F   h e l l o   

 w o
72 6C 64    r l d
```

WHat am I doing wrong?

**edit :** 
I am sorry but i try edit my code

```
listofchar = map(lambda x: "%s" % x,data)
```

here

```
listofchar = map(lambda x: repr(r"%s") % x,data)
```

but output is`

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 0D 0A 77 6F   'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' ' ' '
' '
' 'w' 'o'
72 6C 64    'r' 'l' 'd'
```

and i try

```
import re
listofchar = map(lambda x: re.escape(r"%s") % x,data)
```

output

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 0D 0A 77 6F   \h \e \l \l \o \  \
\
\w \o
72 6C 64    \r \l \d
```

and i try

```
listofchar = map(lambda x: r"%s".replace("\\","\\\\") % x,data)
```

output is

```
68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 0D 0A 77 6F   h e l l o   

 w o
72 6C 64    r l d
```

and many way but i forgot that

i am sorry T^T

Comment: Where are you expecting the two characters \n to come from as you print out one character at a time? Where are you doing the escape you mention in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a way to leave normal characters alone but just encode the special ones.

```
listofchar = map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape'), data)
```

Note that you can use a list comprehension instead of `map` and this is the preferred way to do it.

```
listofchar = [x.encode('unicode-escape') for x in data]
```